# How to Load Square Payment Form in Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom, square, square-connect

I am trying to create a Web Component for the Square Payment form, but am having trouble getting it to load into the shadow DOM.

I am wondering whether or not this is possible, since the form is populated with a script from the Square CDN.

Has anyone had any luck with this use case?

I am using code from an example on https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form
and inserting it into a Web Component template.

The full code example is on Codepen.

https://codepen.io/kvnapavl/pen/BRQZrx?editors=1000#0

```
<base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>

<dom-module id="square-payment-form">

<template>

  // Square payment form code from https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form

</template>

<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'square-payment-form'

  });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time you won't be able to use the Square e-commerce form inside the shadow dom. I'd recommend keeping it in the light .

Comment: So, to be clear, if one were building a progressive web application based on something like Polymer Starter Kit, a different payments provider would have to be used?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  AFAIK if an element is contained in an application shell that uses shadow DOM, it is considered light.  https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom

Comment: Sorry, I mean that you won't be able to use the e-commerce form from within a component (the javascript library can't traverse into the component's shadow dom to create the iframes). For the Polymer Starter Kit you could still stick the e-commerce form into your index.html outside of `<my-app>`.